# Find -exec and Bash scripts

Tags: linux, bash

I'm writing a script in bash.
I invoke it with

```
find *.zip -type f -exec ./myscript.sh {} \;
```

At the top of my script I invoke another script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
. ticktick.sh
```

I get the following error

```
.: ticktick.sh: file not found
```

If I invoke the script like this

```
./myscript.sh somefile.zip
```

it works
If I put the ticktick.sh script in my path in another directory it breaks, so that isn't an option. Is there some special kind of context that scripts called with a find have? I'm obviously new to BASH scripting. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I think there are 2 problems.

1.: if you want to search for all zip files in the current directory, you have to write the following command

```
find . -type f -name *.zip -exec ...
```

2.: you execute myscript.sh with ./ before it. So myscript.sh has to be in the current working directory. if your script is in /home/jd/ and you execute it from /home/ your myscript.sh will be not found.
first you have to determine the directory of your files:

```
install_path=$(dirname $(readlink -f $0))
```

So your complete find command is:

```
find . -type f -name *.zip -exec $install_path/myscript.sh {} \;
```

The myscript.sh file have to be in the same directory as ticktick.sh